# Disable user interaction for UIButton of type RoundedRect via code

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I wand to disable userinteraction for a UIButton of type RoundedRect. I tried

```
[previousAudio userInteractionEnabled:NO];
```

But got the exception
Terminating app due to uncaught exception `NSInvalidArgumentException`, reason: `-[UIRoundedRectButton userInteractionEnabled:]:` unrecognized selector sent to instance

what can I do instead to disable userinteraction ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use  `previousAudio.enabled = NO OR YES` instad of `[previousAudio userInteractionEnabled:NO];`

Comment: The "enabled flag is _not_ the same as the "userInteractionEnabled" flag. See documentation for more details, but basically the "enabled" flag can/will also have an impact on the look of the button.  If that effect is desired, then the "enabled" flag is the right one to use, but the confusion in the original question is between "setUserInteractionEnabled" and "userInteractionEnabled". The "set" version is used with the [ ] brackets notation, while the latter is used with the dot notation. Also see rdelmar's answer below.

Comment: @ErikvanderNeut i am not said in my answer you can not use `userInteractionEnabled` i just suggest to you can use Button enable YES or NO Because for button if you are used Enable yes not as par UI you can notice that display UI touchable but when you use  userInteractionEnabled user can not identifier is that buttonis touchable or not that's the reason i suggest enable YES NO

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @Nitin. You are right, the "enabled" is a better choice if you want to reflect the change in the look and feel of the button. -- What I wanted to clarify is that you got the "unrecognized selector sent to instance" error because you used [previousAudio userInteractionEnabled:NO] instead of [previousAudio setUserInteractionEnabled:NO] or previousAudio.userInteractionEnabled = NO.  Just wanted to make sure you were aware of that difference between the dot notation (which I personally prefer) and the [ ] bracket notation.

Answer (score 3):

It should be:

```
[previousAudio setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```

or

```
previousAudio.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Answer (score 1):

Because there's no `userInteractionEnabled:` selector. `userInteractionEnabled` is getter. In order to set property you should use `button.userInteractionEnabled = NO` or `[button setUserInteractionEnabled:NO]`

Answer (score 0):

Use **setUserInteractionEnabled:NO** instead of **userInteractionEnabled:NO**

```
[previousAudio setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```

It doesn't matter that your button is roundedRect or has some other property.

Answer (score -1):

you can set it as desiabled `previousAudio.enabled = NO` or you can set a condition in the iBAction method

```
-(IBAction)previousAudioPressed:(id)sender{

    if (condition ){
            //do something
    }

}
```